# Non-unitary magnetic translation operator for Landau levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, hamiltonian, unitarity, quantum-hall-effect

In chapter 9 of their book [1], Altland and Simons consider the Landau Hamiltonian in the symmetric gauge,
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{1}{2m^*}\left[\left(-\mathrm{i}\partial_1-\frac{x_2}{2l_0^2}\right)^2+\left(-\mathrm{i}\partial_2+\frac{x_1}{2l_0^2}\right)^2\right],
\end{equation}
where $l_0=\sqrt{\Phi_0/2\pi|B|}$ is the magnetic length. They demonstrate that the state $\psi_n=z^n\exp(-|z|^2/4l_0^2)$ has energy $\epsilon_n=\frac{B}{m^*}(n+1/2)$, and then argue that the degeneracy of this $n^{\text{th}}$ Landau level can be found as follows. (I have paraphrased for succinctness.)

> Define operators
> \begin{align} 
> & k =\partial_z-\frac{\bar{z}}{4l_0^2},
>  && \bar{k} = \partial_{\bar{z}}+\frac{z}{4l_0^2} 
> \end{align}
> which satisfy $[H, k]=[H, \bar{k}]=0$ and $[k, \bar{k}]=1/2l_0^2$. From these, define
> \begin{align} 
> &T = \exp\left[\frac{4\pi l_0^2}{L}k\right], &&U = \exp\left[\mathrm{i}\frac{2\pi l_0^2}{L}\bar{k}\right] 
> \end{align}
> where $L$ is the spatial extent of the system. $T$ and $U$ satisfy the magnetic algebra
> \begin{equation} 
> TU = UT\exp\left[4\pi^2\mathrm{i}\left(\frac{l_0}{L}\right)^2\right].
> \end{equation}
> This implies that the states $\psi_{n, m}=\text{const.}\times T^m\psi_n$ satisfy
> \begin{equation}
> U\psi_{n,m}=\exp\left[-\mathrm{i}4\pi^2
> m\left(\frac{l_0}{L}\right)^2\right]\psi_{n,m}; 
> \end{equation}
> the eigenvalue of $\psi_{n,m}$ under $U$ is different for $m=1, \ldots, 2\pi(L/l_0)^2$, and thus each Landau level is $2\pi(L/l_0)^2$-fold degenerate.

I have a few problems with this argument:

1. As defined, the operators $T$ and $U$ are not unitary. I'm not sure if this is a problem, but it makes me feel slightly uneasy. Usually, one sees magnetic translation operators defined as $\sim t(\mathbf{d}) = \exp(\mathrm{i}\mathbf{d}\cdot(-\mathrm{i}\nabla-e\mathbf{A}))$, and these *are* unitary - so I don't understand why A&S have chosen to use a different definition.
2. If $2\pi(L/l_0)^2$ is not an integer (and is, say, irrational), then this argument appears to break as the value of $\exp[-\mathrm{i}4\pi^2 m(l_0/L)^2]$ is then different for all $m$.
3. The operator $U$ is defined to contain a factor of $\mathrm{i}$ inside the exponential, but $T$ does not include this factor. This seems somewhat arbitrary and moreover seems to affect the argument: if we had chosen to include a factor of $\mathrm{i}$ in the exponent of $T$ also, then the magnetic algebra would read $TU = UT\exp\left[-4\pi^2\left(\frac{l_0}{L}\right)^2\right]$ and the state $\psi_{n, m}$ would have eigenvalue $\exp[4\pi^2 m(l_0/L)^2]$ under $U$ which is different for *all* integers $m$, even if $2\pi(L/l_0)^2$ is an integer.
4. For that matter, why is it even necessary to include the system size $L$ in the definitions of $U$ and $T$? Surely we could just as well choose any other length? Of course $L$ is a characteristic length scale of the problem, but this is not very satisfactory.

**How can these issues be resolved?**

I am aware that for an infinite plane the degeneracy of each Landau level is infinite, and I suspect that points 2-4 reflect this fact. However, I am not sure how to formalise this.

I am also aware that the states $\psi_{n, m}$ have a spatial extent larger than $L$ for $m>2\pi(L/l_0)^2$, so such states are not physically valid, but I would like to justify this heuristic argument more rigorously.

I have a feeling that the whole approach is fundamentally flawed, and that the only concrete way to calculate the degeneracy is by analysing the Landau level problem on a compact manifold such as a torus (e.g. by imposing periodic boundary conditions). This problem is well-documented in the literature, and it is possible that A&S are trying to combine these approaches here. Is anyone able to comment on this?

---

[1] Altland, A., & Simons, B. (2010). *Condensed Matter Field Theory* (2nd ed.). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9780511789984